# How to select option value from the browser console in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I select one of the list values from the browser console?
Thank you for guiding me

```html
<select style="width: 100%" 
        id="Select1" 
        class="css-dropdowns ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched ng-valid-parse"
        name="Select2" 
        ng-model="MP.MP2.MP3ID" 
        required="">
  <option value="" selected="selected">select</option>                           
  <option ng-repeat="o in selectOptions" ng-selected="false" value="1" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
M1
  </option>
  <option ng-repeat="o in " ng-selected="false" value="2" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> M2
  </option>
  <option ng-repeat="o in selectOptions" ng-selected="false" value="3" class="ng-binding ng-scope">                                                       
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

In order to reach elements from the DOM, you can use the [querySelector functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

So to start, you could simply find the element with the id #Select1.

```
let selectElement = document.querySelector('#Select1');
```

Afterwards you would need to be able to reach the "option" values in the "select" that you reached (I'm leaving this part to you, you can look through the MDN documentation I shared above).

In order to mark an option as selected, you can simply say

```
option.selected = true;
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Do you have a Chrome browser too?

Comment: @kooroskabir Sure, and the functionality should be fine with Chrome and Firefox if that's what you meant. :)

Comment: Thanks But I'm having trouble using this code، Can you explain more

Comment: I use code: document.getElementsByName('UserFavoriteColor')[0].selectedIndex=2

Comment: With this method Angular does not accept the selected value